# Virtual function unresolved external error

Tags: c++, oop, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008

MyTask.h

```
class MyTask
{
   virtual std::ostream& show(std::ostream &os) const ;
};
```

MyTask.cpp

```
std::ostream& MyTask::show(std::ostream &os) const
{
os << "Task(" << this->id << "):\t Processing time:" << this->p << "\t Weight:"<< this->w ;
return os;
}
```

I get an unresolved external linking error when I add the word virtual in the header file. I've checked similar questions but the problem was either the function was not defined or it is not pure virtual.

EDIT:
The exact error is:

```
MiniOS.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > & __thiscall SimOS::MyTask::show(class std::basic_ostream<char,struct std::char_traits<char> > &)const " (?show@MyTask@SimOS@@UBEAAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@AAV34@@Z)
```

So I think the problem is something else, any ideas?

Comment: What's the exact description of the error?

Comment: I added the exact description, thanks.

Comment: @YochaiTimmer I did that and it doesn't work :(

Comment: did you include <ostream> to get `std::ostream`?

Comment: @TonyTheLion yes, when I remove 'virtual' it works!

Comment: Is the `show` method actually called by anything? Does it compile and link if you comment the first line of the function?

Comment: @Bathsheba I just answered the question, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I added the MyTask.cpp file as an existing item to the project. And since VS doesn't copy the MyTask.cpp to the current project, I had to remove the file from the project then copy it to the current project and clean then rebuild.
Thanks all for your help.

Comment: I don't understand ... if it doesn't copy it, Visual Studio won't compile it?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly is done, but try it on VS2008 Express Edition

Comment: So you say it compiled without `virtual`, but then you copied the file to the current project folder and, miraccously, it worked. You ask me to install that compiler to explai your voodoo here :) ?

Comment: Since it kept the file in another folder other than the project folder, it is possible that the compiler didn't see the definition of the virtual function that's why it assumed that it is not defined, but I'm not sure. And yes that's a miracle you should be interested to see it yourself :)

Comment: I did some tests with Visual Studio 2008, the full version. I won't install the Express Edition since I'm not sure how to reinstall the full version. Anyway, your explanation to the problem (not reproductible with the full version) seems too fantastic to be true, I think you deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: Anyway as a safety procedure always make sure that when you "Add an Existing item" it gets copied to the local directory of the project. I'll try to capture a video to show you the issue, when I have time.

Comment: It works without copying it to the current folder, it only needs read access there. That's not the problem, especially since it WORKED in your case without the `virtual` keyword, so it did FIND the implementation. You still didn't get my downvote :D

Comment: I get it, I just don't care as long as it works for me:D

Comment: By wasting the time of everyone else? (going out of here in tears, never to be back again)

Comment: I didn't mean to waste your time, but I'm pretty sure that there is someone else in this world that will need this piece of information. What I meant is that your downvote doesn't change anything in the fact that this is an issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44725/discussion-between-liviu-and-poka-yoke)